# Regular expression to match a string containing specific character if not surrounded by whitespace

Tags: regex

Looking for a regex string that would match all alpha numeric character plus a few special ones that include + and -.  Our current regex looks like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_,\.\-' ]+$
```

However, we need to also include the `+` and `-` as well so long as they are not surrounded by whitespace on either side.  For example an `A+ BC` would match, but not `A + BC`.

Tried using word boundaries and haven't been successful.  Any ideas?

Comment: There are some subtle edge cases in to this problem that could be resolved by example. Please address the following questions: Would `+ABC` be considered a match? What about `+ ABC`? What about `ABC +`? What about `- ++ -`? What about `- + -`?

Comment: Download expresso, make two lists, one of strings that should pass, another of ones that should fail. put them one after another in the Sample Text panel, and then work on your regex and use the validate button to see what does and doesn't match, until you get the regex perfect.

Comment: @Asaph - True, it's a subtle edge case where either character is the first or last character in the list.  In either case we would say that so long as there is another character next to it, it would be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you want to accept blocks of `+` and `-`, but only if there's a character on either side. This seems to work well:

```
^([\w\s.,']|\b[+-]+|[+-]+\b)+$
```

#### Explanation:

This regex can only take `+` or `-` if it can find a matching character before or after them.

One or more of:
`[\w\s.,']` - Alphanumeric, white space, dot, comma or apostrophe.
OR
`\b[+-]+` - Alphanumeric, dot, comma or apostrophe, followed by a block of `+-`
OR
`[+-]+\b` - A block of `+-` followed by an alphanumeric, dot, comma or apostrophe.

#### Test cases:

Accepts:
`a+ bv.`
`a+2`
`A+ B -C`
`A+B`
`+1 -2`
`2+++-1 +1 ++3`
`2++++`
`1++ 2`

Rejects: `A + BC`
`a|+3`
`>+a`
`A - B`
`2+++-1 +1 ++`
`++++`
`+`

#### Other:

Word boundaries may don't play well here because a `+` is a word boundary. It did work on [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/), but your flavor may be different. This will also work: `^([\w\s.,']|[\w.,'][+-]+|[+-]+[\w.,'])+$`

Comment: This worked as well but I think this is easier to understand and maintain without introducing errors.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
(([^ ]|^)[-+] ?| ?[-+]([^ ]|$))
```

That should match any `-` or `+` which has some non-space character on either one of the sides (so `A+ BC`, `-` or `A -BC`).

If you want to include alphanumerics in that, you could do it like this:

```
((([^ ]|^)[-+] ?| ?[-+]([^ ]|$))|[a-zA-Z...]+)
```

And then repeat it:

```
^((([^ ]|^)[-+] ?| ?[-+]([^ ]|$))|[a-zA-Z...]+)+$
```

This will match, for example, `A+ B -C` and `A+B`, but not `A - B`.

Comment: The use of `[^ ]` opens the door to other characters. For example, your regex accepts `:+123`, or `a|+3`.

Comment: D'oh! Alright, well, that should be the `[a-zA-Z0-9...]` sequence then.

Comment: I substituted my character class for yours, so it's still good.